# Loop regression analysis with nominal variable

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression

I am doing a multiple univariate linear regression from a database with nominal and continuous variable. I am using a loop function found in StackOverflow.

Here the code:

```
y<- data.frame(final1[-17])
x <- data.frame(final1$other$VO2.max)

out <- data.frame(NULL)              # create object to keep results
for (i in 1:length(y)) {
  m <- summary(lm(y[,i] ~ x[,1]))    # run model
  out[i, 1] <- names(y)[i]           # print variable name
  out[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   # intercept
  out[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,4]   # pvalue
  out[i, 4] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   # Estimate or beta value
  out[i, 5] <- m$coefficients[2,2]   # standard error of the estimate
}

names(out) <- c("y.variable", "intercept", "p.value","Estimate.beta","Std.Error")

out
```

When I use a database with only numerical variables no problem occurs. With nominal variables I get this error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

In my database, there are no missing values in the independent variable, only some missing in the dependent variable.
I like this function and way to run and present the results of the univariate and I would like to create a final table with nominal and numerical predictors.

What should I do, run only the numerical variables and one by one the nominal variables?

Thank you in advance